# changing the title of a tooltip based on the value of a selected:option and outputting to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the value of (12-400mm) for example to show in a tooltip for the input box.

This is the HTML for the select box and the input box

```
<label for="select-sector"><b>Fire Rating</b></label>
<select class="form-control" id="fire">
<option value="12mm-400mm" id="1">90/30</option>
<option value="0mm-250mm" id="1">60/30</option>
<option value="0mm-100mm" id="1">120/60</option>

<div class="void form-group" id="void">
<label for="input-void"><b>Void Gap</b> (in millimeters)</label>
<input type="number" value="" placeholder="Input" class="form-control" 
data-placement="bottom" title="gap" id="voidinput" />
```

Here is the Jquery, when alerted out the value displays fine.

```
<script>
    $("#fire").change(function() {
        var firevoid = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $('#voidinput').tooltip("The void range of this product is between" + firevoid);
    });


    $('#voidinput').tooltip({
        content: voidrange
    });

    function voidrange() {
        return "The void range of this product is between" + firevoid;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `voidrange` method doesn't know anything about `firevoid` variable. `firevoid` only available inside `change event` function. you need to declare `firevoid` outside of `change event` function, e.g: `var firevoid; $("#fire").change(function() { firevoid = ...`

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this still isn't working for me. I have:   var firevoid;
        $("#fire").change(function() {
            firevoid = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            alert("The void range of this product is between" + firevoid);
            $('#void').tooltip({
                content: function() {
                    return $(firevoid);
                }
            });
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume you using bootstrap's tooltip plugin*

You need to fix couple of things in your code first:

- You added same `id` to `option` elements. `id` should be unique in `HTML` document. there is no need to add `id` to `option` though.
- For getting `select`'s current value, you don't need to find selected `option`, just `$('#fire').val()` is enough.

So, if I got you correctly, here is the code that you need:

```
var $input = $('#voidinput');

$("#fire").on('change', function() {   
    $input
        .attr('title', "The void range of this product is between" + $(this).val())
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');        
});
```

Basically every time the selected option changes, you need to change the `title` attribute of `input` and then call [`tooltip`'s api methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips) to show the updated tooltip.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/t4nry617/)

Comment: You sir are the man! and should be applauded. Thank you for the help, it is much appreciated!!!!